# Is there any way to create update history using Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Data Structure**

```
Categories
|
--- GfyBM6PaPugURNO3XY3s (Document)
    |
    --- Category Name (String)
    --- Last Update Of Sub Categories (Timestamp)
    --- Sub Categories (Sub Collection)
        |
        --- b6CmXCUuIiFM5wWhNNty (Document)
        --- c20P7Usnd7GUfPh8rI5l (Document)
        --- L9YS3HEq5lPYmkRDhEsH (Document)
        --- etc... to 37 documents
            |
            --- Sub Category Name (String)
```

I have 37 sub categories inside categories collection and the admin can rename any sub category but currently, I comparing this field `Last Update Of Sub Categories (Timestamp)` local value against online value, If the comparing was different then I'll delete all sub categories locally and read sub categories again from online and that will cost 37 reads.

What do I need? I need to read the sub category who renamed only instead of reading all sub categories and that will cost me only 1 or 2 reads depending on how many changes are there.

Any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here may be you can find your answer.

URLS

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data